# iOS weird behaviour of autolayout

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I'm writing my app only through code (not using storyboards).
I have 1 tabBarController and 4 tabs (UINavigationControllers) to it. I also added an animated indicator to show which tab is currently selected.
In one of those tabs there is an UITableView that I stretch to the bounds of its superview as so:

```
 func  stretchToBoundsOfSuperView() -> [NSLayoutConstraint] {
    let constraints =
    NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("H:|[item]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["item" : self]) +
        NSLayoutConstraint.constraintsWithVisualFormat("V:|[item]|", options: [], metrics: nil, views: ["item" : self])
    if let superview = self.superview {
        superview.addConstraints(constraints)
    }
    return constraints 
 }
```

I call this function on the tableView variable in viewDidLoad function of course after I add it to its superview.

for some reason I get a very strange behaviour when this tab first loads, I added a video to show that behaviour. For demoing purposes i set the background color of the tableView to green, and the ViewController's view set to gray and set the slow animations on in the simulator.

in the video i display what happens when i select the tab with the UITableView for the first time.

https://youtu.be/0CqsrEu4YOQ

help would be much appreciated, thanks

Comment: Are you subclassing `UITableView`? Or is `stretchToBoundsOfSuperView` an extension? Cause subclassing `UITableView` is not recommended.

Comment: no, this function is an extension of UIView. I think this behaviour that shows in this example happening to a tableView actually happens to any view i will try to stretch to the superview's bounds in this viewController.

Comment: You should probably call this in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Comment: ok i figured it out. i created an loading indicator view that animates itself to expand and collapse in size (through constraints). what happened is that i used that custom view in the 'viewDidLoad' controller function and made that indicator active thus unknowingly calling an 'UIView.animateWithDuration' call with 'layoutIfNeeded' to the superview. thus creating an animation before the controller even appeared causing weird animations to the whole view because 'layoutIfNeeded' was called. now that i changed it the problem is gone. thank u guys either way.

Comment: @Paulw11 can u explain the significant of not building constraints in viewDidLoad?